# Reject external files dragged in a DropArea without breaking the DropArea

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In my application I'm displaying a list of audio files and the user can drag an external file to add it to the list. I want to be able to refuse the drag if no file in the list is supported by my application.

The issue is that when I call `drag.accepted = false;` in `onEntered` of my `DropArea` then it becomes completely unresponsive to any other event.

Here is some sample code showing the issue. If you drag an MP3 in the window you see that it works. Then if you drag any other file it won't work, as expected. But then dragging an `MP3` file back will not work either.

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
  title: qsTr("Hello World")
  width: 640
  height: 480

  DropArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onEntered: {
      console.log("[Droparea] entered");

      // Ensure at least one file is supported before accepted the drag
      var validFile = false;
      for(var i = 0; i < drag.urls.length; i++) {
        if(validateFileExtension(drag.urls[i])) {
          validFile = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if(!validFile) {
        console.log("No valid files, refusing drag event");
        drag.accepted = false;
        return false;
      }
    }

    onExited: {
      console.log("[Droparea] entered");

    }

    onDropped: {
      console.log("[Droparea] dropped");
    }

    // Only MP3s
    function validateFileExtension(filePath) {
      var extension = filePath.split('.').pop();
      var valid = false;

      if(extension == "mp3") {
        valid = true;
      }

      return valid;
    }
  }

  Text {
    id: textDrop
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    text: "Please drag element"
  }

}
```

Is there a bug in the `DropArea` or did I misunderstood something? I know I can filter the files in the onDropped but then you loose the visual feedback you get on OSX when dragging file on an area that does not accept them.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am now dealing with the exact same problem.

Comment: No I ended up accepting the files and then just filtering the ones I want myself

Comment: this is fixed in Qt 5.6.

Answer (score 6):

It has been a [known bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39453) for a long time. A patch has been submitted and after been stalled for several months is now [merged into **5.6 branch**](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/88612/).

---

***Anyone who wants to use this functionality MUST upgrade to Qt 5.6 or MANULLY integrate the available patch into his/her Qt version.***

---

[`QQuickDropAreaPrivate`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtdeclarative/source/6dc8f47bb05a8acb3cbcc697e0dc05356a01d4cf:src/quick/items/qquickdroparea.cpp#L83-269), contained in `DropArea`, updates the [`containsDrag`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-droparea.html#containsDrag-prop) flag to `true` when a `dragEnterEvent` occurs, emitting the [`entered`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-droparea.html#entered-signal) signal. It updates `containsDrag` to `false` when a`dragLeaveEvent` occurs, emitting an [`exited`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-droparea.html#exited-signal) signal. However, when the drag event is not accepted `dragLeaveEvent` is never called, leaving the private object in a incosistent state. Each subsequent `dragEnterEvent` is discarded since `containsDrag` is still `true`, i.e. the previous drag event is still considered active and the `entered` is no more emitted.

Since the issue is related to an interaction between private APIs and usage of the public APIs, the problem *does not* affect filtering using [`keys`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-droparea.html#keys-prop). Unfortunately, this approach does not seem to fit for the presented use case.

A **quite partial** workaround is to use a `MouseArea` along with the `DropArea`. The latter disables itself when a rejection occurs while the former enables back the `DropArea` for the next drop. This workaround covers the common case in which a wrong item is dropped *inside* the `DropArea`, which is the most common and intuitive for an end user. Releasing the wrong item *outside* the `DropArea` invalidate the mechanism (until the next drop).

Here's the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        enabled: !drop.enabled
        onContainsMouseChanged: drop.enabled = true
    }

    DropArea {
        id: drop
        anchors.fill: parent

        onEntered: {
            console.log("[Droparea] entered");
            // Ensure at least one file is supported before accepted the drag
            for(var i = 0; i < drag.urls.length; i++)
                if(validateFileExtension(drag.urls[i]))
                    return
            console.log("No valid files, refusing drag event")
            drag.accept()
            drop.enabled = false
        }

        onExited: console.log("[Droparea] exited")

        onDropped: console.log("[Droparea] dropped")

        // Only MP3s
        function validateFileExtension(filePath) {
            return filePath.split('.').pop() == "mp3"
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: textDrop
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Please drag element"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you never put accepteed = true

just add drag.accepted = true after you set the valid as valid

```
for(var i = 0; i < drag.urls.length; i++) {
    if(validateFileExtension(drag.urls[i])) {
      validFile = true;
      drag.accepted = true;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tried this already and it does not change anything. Accepting the drag behaves the same way as doing nothing