# Drag and Drop not works as expected

Tags: drag-and-drop, qml, qtquick2

I have 2 identical `Item`s in the scene. Each one can be dragged and also accepts interaction with other dragged objects. To avoid interactions with itself I set `drop.accept = false` in appropriate drag functions. It works fine when I drag for example `rect1` over `rect2`. `rect2` responds to entering and exiting events. But if after that I try to move `rect2` over `rect1` the drag mechanism stops working and dragging events are not called at all, even if I again move `rect1` over `rect2`.

My target is to know, at each moment of dragging, what object is dragged and on which objects it is moved over.

```js
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: win
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        id:  rect1
        objectName: "rect1"
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 200
        y: 200
        color: "orange"
        property bool hold: false
        z: hold ? 2 : 1
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "rect1"
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: area1
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: rect1.hold ? rect1 : undefined
            onPressed: rect1.hold = true;
            onReleased: rect1.hold = false;
        }
        DropArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onEntered: {
                if(drag.source == rect1) {
                    drag.accepted = false;
                }
                else{
                    drag.accepted = true;
                    console.log("rect1: entered");
                }
            }
            onExited: {
                if(drag.source == rect1) {
                    drag.accepted = false;
                }
                else {
                    drag.accepted = true;
                    console.log("rect1: exited");
                }
            }
        }
        Drag.active: rect1.hold
        Drag.source: rect1.hold ? rect1 : undefined
        Drag.hotSpot: Qt.point(width/2,height/2)
    }

    Rectangle {
        id:  rect2
        objectName: "rect2"
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 500
        y: 300
        color: "lightblue"
        property bool hold: false
        z: hold ? 2 : 1
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "rect2"
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: area2
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: rect2.hold ? rect2 : undefined
            onPressed: rect2.hold = true;
            onReleased: rect2.hold = false;
        }
        DropArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onEntered: {
                if(drag.source == rect2) {
                    drag.accepted = false;
                }
                else {
                    drag.accepted = true;
                    console.log("rect2: entered");
                }
            }
            onExited: {
                if(drag.source == rect2) {
                    drag.accepted = false;
                }
                else {
                    drag.accepted = true;
                    console.log("rect2: exited");
                }
            }
        }

        Drag.active: rect2.hold
        Drag.source: rect2.hold ? rect2 : undefined
        Drag.hotSpot: Qt.point(width/2,height/2)
    }
}
```

Comment: [DropArea is bugged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28800328/2538363), that's most probably the source of the issue you are facing. I don't think the workaround proposed in the linked answer matches your use case, though.

Comment: Thanks @BaCaRoZzo for the link, that's exactly the same bag as mine. Ok, it looks that problem inside Qt so it's nothing to do here. Have to think how to avoid setting `drop.accept`